# How to fetch the messaging of linkedin user

Tags: c#, linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin, linkedin-gem

I wanted to fetch the messages that was sent to the other connected linkedin users.

I found a code sample to send the message in this site
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sample-code-sending-message

But, I did not any sample to fetch the messages.
However, when I tried to fetch the message with the query "/people/~/mailbox", I got the error
"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

In detail error message, I got "Access to mailbox denied".

These 2 documentations has listed only the Primary Endpoints "POST /people/~/mailbox" but has not mentioned about GET.

https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-10a-overview
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#oauth2-redirect-uri

Is there any way to fetch the message? Or Is there any workaround?
Any insights or help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you obtain an API key from LinkedIn?...and put it in the script?...without an API key, you won't have authorization to access the API, the "user" also need to be logged into to their LinkedIn account.

Comment: Yes.I have obtained API key and used in my code. The user also logged into the Linkedin account.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Linkedin Inbox is supported any longer through their API. As per [this answer on quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-start-using-LinkedIn-Inbox-API),

> API is not publicly available but has been made available to several
>   partners. The best thing to do is contact LinkedIn's BD team for
>   access.

I was not able to see any specific mention to this type of access in their documentation.

Furthermore, check out [APIGEE Snapshot for LinkedIn's 3 main API categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmVLw.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Changed the response. Hopefully added more clarification.